How can I implement regression after multi-class multi-label classification?
I have a dataset where some objects (15%) belong to different classes and have a property value for each of those classes. How can I make a model that predicts multi-label or multi-class and then make a regression prediction based on the output of the classifier? I also need to output the probabilities for each class. unfortunately I can't delete this 15%.
enter image description here
I have no idea how to put it together. I have only found how to implement it separately. Any advice?

What's wrong with doing it separately?

You may be looking for a multi-output neural network, but I'm not sure what advantage this would provide of two models called in sequence.  In fact it would likely be much harder to implement.

Yes, I was thinking about multi-output neural network but the problem is that I don't quite understand how it would work to simultaneously predict the property and the classes the object belongs to. That's why I was thinking about splitting into two models, but I find this solution too complicated and not optimal.

Also, the property depends on classes, which can be one or more, which means that I should get from one to N values at the output of the regression.
